# Are there any emulator for AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vagrant, aws-lambda

I want to run Go service on AWS Lambda by [this instruction](http://blog.0x82.com/2014/11/24/aws-lambda-functions-in-go/) without actually using AWS Lambda service. Looking for a vagrant or vbox which can emulating Lambda. I know it's a weird request. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few options (from damn simple to more complete)

1. [Node Lambda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-lambda) – Command line tool to locally run and remotely deploy your node.js applications to Amazon Lambda.

   - Custom event used to simulate an input similar to what Lambda would get on AWS.
   - Allows testing locally, simulating AWS Lambda environment.
   - Deploy

---

2. [grunt-aws-lambda](https://github.com/Tim-B/grunt-aws-lambda) – Grunt plugin to assist in developing functions for AWS Lambda.

   - All of the above
   - Function packaging (ZIP)
   - Separation of environments (dev, test, production)
   - Adds stripping and packaging of function before deploying (including only necessary packages).

---

3. [serverless (formerly JAWS)](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) – Complete application framework to build applications based on different services in AWS (that relies heavily on AWS Lambda).

   - All of the above
   - Includes boilerplate setup
   - Simulates an API gateway to test locally

---

Hope this is useful.